# MySQL keyword search?

Tags: mysql, keyword

I have a column in which there are two keyword `google plus` .How can i search from from my data base when i have the exact one word like `google` or `plus` or both of them `google plus` and not `goo` or `plu`.

I have tried to get to my needs with `LIKE` function but didn't helped.

thanks

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a good use for a relational database or LIKE.  You want something like Lucene that can index values and allow you to do searches.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT keyword FROM tablename WHERE keyword LIKE '%google%' OR keyword LIKE '%plus%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
col LIKE '%google%' OR col LIKE '%plus%' OR col LIKE '%google plus%'
```